# Warning: unpack(): Type f: not enough input, need 4, have 2

Tags: php, stl-file

Создаю веб-приложение, которое считает объём 3D модели. Проблема заключается в том, что когда я начинаю считывать данные из файла (3D модель формата .stl), то вылезает данная ошибка, причём неоднократно.

```
<?php

$filename = "C:/xampp/tmp/" .basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']);
$count = 3;
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$header = fread($handle, 80);
$rnum = fread($handle, 4);
$num = unpack('I', $rnum);
print_r($num);
$sum = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i< $num; $i++) {
    $contents = fread($handle, 4);
    $normal1 = unpack('f', fread($handle, 4));
    $contents = fread($handle, 4);
    $normal2 = unpack('f', $contents);
    $contents = fread($handle, 4);
    $normal3 = unpack('f', $contents);
        
    $contents = fread($handle, 4);
    $vertex11 = unpack('f', $contents);
    $contents = fread($handle, 4);
    $vertex12 = unpack('f', $contents);
    $contents = fread($handle, 4);
    $vertex13 = unpack('f', $contents);
    
    $contents = fread($handle, 4);
    $vertex21 = unpack('f', $contents);
    $contents = fread($handle, 4);
    $vertex22 = unpack('f', $contents);
    $contents = fread($handle, 4);
    $vertex23 = unpack('f', $contents);
    

    $contents = fread($handle, 4);
    $vertex31 = unpack('f', $contents);
    $contents = fread($handle, 4);
    $vertex32 = unpack('f', $contents);
    $contents = fread($handle, 4);
    $vertex33 = unpack('f', $contents);
    
    $atrib = fread($handle, 2);
    
    $sum = $sum + ((float)$vertex31 * (float)$vertex22);//на формулу не обращайте внимания. Просто тест.
    
} 
fclose($handle);
print($sum);
?>
```

Comment: хм. я же писал вчера коммент. странно. В общем, ошибка появляется несколько раз за счет цикла в одной строке? либо в разных строках?

Comment: А можно пример файла?

Comment: @teran Ошибка появляется в каждой строке, где я использую unpack при каждой итерации.

Comment: @E_p Для теста подойдёт любая 3D моделька в формате .stl(только её бинарный вариант)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код что бы вытащить координаты:

```
<?php

  const HEADER_BYTES = 80;
  const FACETS_COUNT_BYTES = 4;

  // Мы будем читать сразу по 3 значения для вектора и вертекса.
  // В теории можно прочитать сразу весь фасет, но тогда "pattern" для чения длинноват будет...
  const VECTOR_SIZE_BYTES = 12; //3*4
  const VERTEX_SIZE_BYTE = 12; // 3*4
  const VERTICES_COUNT = 3;
  const FACET_END_BYTES = 2;

  // Патерн для получения массива с элементами x, y, z. где тип переменной g  - float (machine dependent size, little endian byte order)
  const TRIPLET_EXTRACT_PATTERN = 'gx/gy/gz';

  $sf = fopen('cube.stl', 'rb');
  $header = fread($sf, HEADER_BYTES);

  $facetsCountBytes = fread($sf, FACETS_COUNT_BYTES);

  // Current  очень важно так как unpack() возвращает массив
  $facetsCount = current(unpack("I", $facetsCountBytes));

  $facets = [];

  for ($i=0; $i<$facetsCount; $i++) {
      $facet =[];
      // Читаем и распоковываем вектор
      // Когда читал по одному элементу а не три сразу, распоковка выдавала ерунду.
      $vectorBytes = fread($sf, VECTOR_SIZE_BYTES);
      $facet['vector'] = unpack(TRIPLET_EXTRACT_PATTERN, $vectorBytes);

      // Читаем и распоковываем вертексы 
      for ($j=1; $j<=VERTICES_COUNT; $j++) {
          $vertexBytes = fread($sf, VERTEX_SIZE_BYTE);
          $facet['vertex'.$j] = unpack(TRIPLET_EXTRACT_PATTERN, $vertexBytes);
      }

      $endBytes = fread($sf, FACET_END_BYTES);
      $facet['end'] = current(unpack('S', $endBytes));

      $facets[] = $facet;
  }

  var_dump($facets);
```

Comment: имена переменных нормальны. а вот использование отдельных переменных вместо матрицы 3х3 и вектора из 3х значений это несколько пугает

Comment: @teran Согласен, неправильно выразился.

Comment: @E_p Здравствуйте. Я уже пробовал этот способ и он ни к чему не приводит. Появляется идентичная ошибка, только вместо 'f' там стоит 'g'.

Comment: @teran Я понимаю, что это выглядит нелепо. Но в первоначальном варианте использовал массивы, но в следствии того, что у меня вылезает столько ошибок, я решил упростить код.

Comment: @Станислав Держите рабочий код. По хорошему, надо выделить в функцию или даже класс.

Comment: @E_p Спасибо огромное